# Filter values with > or < using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, filter

I want to create a function that can take in any dataframe, choose a column with ints an specify a number to filter out data if it's > the specified number.

```
def findFilter(df, transType, columnName=None, filterNumber=None):
            if transType == 'filter<>':
             if filterOperator == '>':
            dfNew = df[~(df[columnName] > filterNumber)]
            return dfNew
```

This returns none, instead of the rows where the value is > the given number.

For example, if I put columnName=days filterNumber=6

```
day      month
1        Jan
4        May
7        Jul
9        Sept
```

I want to return:

```
day      month
7        Jul
9        Sept
```

Comment: where are you getting `filterOperator`. That is not an argument to your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### To answer the question...

You have a few problems:

- You have a stray `if` condition at the top of your function
- You use `filterOperator` within your function but define `transType` in the function definition.
- Using `~` negates your condition, so instead of finding records `> filterNumber`, you are finding records `< filterNumber`

This revised function works per the example and could be refined if desired:

```
def findFilter(df, filterOperator, columnName=None, filterNumber=None):
        if filterOperator == '>':
            dfNew = df[(df[columnName] > filterNumber)]
            return dfNew
        else:
            print('Error')
            return None

findFilter(df, ">", "day", 6)
```

#### But there is a better way...

That said, there are much simpler ways of doing this in pandas -- e.g., `df.loc[df['day'] > 6]`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
df[df['day'] > 6]
```

This filters the rows by the column  'day' being greater than 6.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def findFilter(df, filterOperator='>', columnName=None, filterNumber=0):
    if filterOperator == '>':
        dfNew = df[df[columnName] > filterNumber]
    return dfNew

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'Jan'], [4, 'May'], [7, 'Jul'], [9, 'Sept']], columns=['day', 'month'])

df = findFilter(df, '>', 'day', 6)
print(df.head())

# or without the function
df = df[df['day'] > 6]
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this flexible for several types of comparisons with `getattr`, since Series have all of the basic comparison operators as attributes. I changed the argument order so it reads more plainly.

```
def findFilter(df, columnName=None, filterOperator='gt', filterVal=None):
    """
    filterOperator : str {'gt', 'ge', 'eq', 'lt, 'le', 'isin'}
    filterVal : numeric (list if filterOperator == 'isin')
    """
    return df[getattr(df[columnName], filterOperator)(filterVal)]

findFilter(df, 'day', 'gt', 6)
#   day month
#2    7   Jul
#3    9  Sept
```

---

It can even take a few other methods

```
findFilter(df, 'month', 'isin', ['Jan', 'Jul'])
#   day month
#0    1   Jan
#2    7   Jul
```